# Weekly Problem Sets for Lang's Undergraduate Algebra and Undergraduate Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, reference-request, self-learning, online-resources

For Lang's *Undergraduate Algebra* and *Undergraduate Analysis,* I cannot find any weekly problem sets online. I've found that doing every problem in every section takes far too long, and without problem sets, I don't know which problems to do without doing all of them.

Does anyone know where I can find online weekly problem sets for these textbooks?

Comment: How's this: https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/BrownClasses/153/index.htm

Comment: @GerryMyerson Helpful.
There are references to a handout I don't have access to for some of the modular arithmetic problems, but I don't think it'll make that much of a difference.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Also, it ends less than halfway through the book, so I'll be back here for a new set of problems next week.

Comment: Well, you can do what I did – type Lang "undergraduate algebra" into Google, and see what comes back at you. Most of it won't be what you want, but with a little patience you might strike it lucky.